# PDF annotations across multiple systems

Tags: pdf, cloud-storage, pdf-viewer, synchronization

I have a lot of PDF-documents I want to annotate with comments or highlight passages. I need this across multiple devices (iOS, Windows7+, maybe macOS, Linux as a bonus), so a cloud service is fine (prefer Google Drive, OneDrive; iCloud and Dropbox may be accepted, too).

Is thera any tool I can accomplish that? Is Adobe Reader with any Cloud Storage already sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) - it is an online service with apps for desktop & mobile that provides:

- Web App
- Desktop Apps for Windows 7+, MacOS & Linux
- iOS & Android Apps
- Online library of pdfs & other materials
- Tagging, Notes and Organisation
- Reference Management
- Co-operation with others on library entries
- PDF viewer
- PDF Highlighting & Annotation
- Export with or without annotations
- Various research tools
- Job Alerts

The amount of storage and various other facilities depend on the plan that you are willing to sign up & pay for but there are free accounts that will let you at least get a feel for how useful it might be.

[image]

Comment: Is it there any other way that doesn't involve using a whole app? I just want to sync pdf annotations. It is just words and highlighting on the same file, but across different systems.

Comment: @AlekFröhlich - the problem is that, unless the file is on a shared resource, each system is likely to have its own **copy** of the file. So you need something that can annotate the file and share that information. If you hosted the pdfs in a shared location and annotated them, *(ensuring syncing)*, then the annotations **should** be shared but **may** not be visible on other systems.

Comment: @AlekFröhlich of course since Mendeley has a Web interface you don't **have** to install an app on each system.